# How to fix command prompt cutting of start of output?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-prompt

For a long time inside of Visual Studio 2019, and also pretty much everywhere else in windows, my command prompt has cut out the first few lines/characters when opening it.

Meaning something like this:
[image]

Ends up looking like this:
[image]

I've tried playing around with the cmd prompt preferences for window and buffer size but it changes nothing.

Does anyone know how to fix this?